# Java optimized Cramers rule function

Tags: java, algorithm, math, matrix, linear-algebra

Recently learned about Cramers rule in precalculus, and decided to make an algorithm in Java to help me understand it better.

The following code works 100% correctly, however it does not use any sort of for loop to do what it does in a much simpler fashion.

Question: Is there a more elegant implementation of Cramers Rule in Java?

I'm thinking that making a basic determinant method, and then doing some column swapping for when I need to take the determinant of Dx, Dy, and Dz. (for Dx, swap column 4 with column 1 of the original matrix, then take determinant and divide by original determinant.) 
This sound good?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = new int[3][3];
    matrix[0] = new int[] { 3, 5, -1, -2 };
    matrix[1] = new int[] { 1, -4, 2, 13 };
    matrix[2] = new int[] { 2, 4, 3, 1 };
    int[] r = crame(matrix);    
    info("x: " + r[0] + ", y: " + r[1] + ", z: " + r[2]);
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        int[] base = matrix[i];
        if(check(base, r, base[3])) {
            info("System " + (i+1) + " checks!");
        } else {
            info("System " + (i+1) + " fails check!");
        }
    }
}

public static int[] crame(int[][] m) {
    int[] result;
    if (m.length == 2) {
        result = new int[2];
        int D = (m[0][0] * m[1][1]) - (m[1][0] * m[0][1]);
        int Dx = (m[0][2] * m[1][1]) - (m[1][2] * m[0][1]);
        int Dy = (m[0][0] * m[1][2]) - (m[1][0] * m[0][2]);
        result[0] = (int) (Dx / D);
        result[1] = (int) (Dy / D);
    } else if (m.length == 3) {
        result = new int[3];

        int D = (((m[0][2] * m[1][1] * m[0][2]) + (m[2][1] * m[1][2] * m[0][0]) + (m[2][2]
                * m[1][0] * m[0][2])) - ((m[0][0] * m[1][1] * m[2][2])
                + (m[0][1] * m[1][2] * m[0][2]) + (m[0][2] * m[1][0] * m[2][1])));

        int Dx = (((m[2][3] * m[1][1] * m[0][2]) + (m[2][1] * m[1][2] * m[0][3]) + (m[2][2]
                * m[1][3] * m[0][1])) - ((m[0][3] * m[1][1] * m[2][2])
                + (m[0][1] * m[1][2] * m[2][3]) + (m[0][2] * m[1][3] * m[2][1])));

        int Dy = (((m[2][0] * m[1][3] * m[0][2]) + (m[2][3] * m[1][2] * m[0][3]) + (m[2][2]
                * m[1][0] * m[0][3])) - ((m[0][0] * m[1][3] * m[2][2])
                + (m[0][3] * m[1][2] * m[2][0]) + (m[0][2] * m[1][0] * m[2][3])));

        int Dz = (((m[2][0] * m[1][1] * m[0][3]) + (m[2][1] * m[1][3] * m[0][0]) + (m[2][3]
                * m[1][0] * m[0][1])) - ((m[0][0] * m[1][1] * m[2][3])
                + (m[0][1] * m[1][3] * m[2][0]) + (m[0][3] * m[1][0] * m[2][1])));

        result[0] = (int) (Dx / D);
        result[1] = (int) (Dy / D);
        result[2] = (int) (Dz / D);
    } else {
        return new int[] {};
    }
    return result;
}

public static int product(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int p = 0;
    int[] fin = new int[(a.length -1)];
    for(int x = 0; x < fin.length; x++) {
        fin[x] = a[x] * b[x];
    }
    for (int f : fin) {
            p += f;
    }
    return p;
}

public static boolean check(int[] a, int[] b, int z) {
    return product(a, b) == z;
}

public static void info(String log) {
    System.out.println(log);
}
```

My question pertains to the specific algorithm that can be used to solve systems of equations using Cramers rule only, is there any algorithm that is more elegant? The function is only designed for square matrices.

This is not a homework assignment, after HS I will be studying CS and I've been working on developing algorithms as preliminary practice.

Thank you for checking this out

Comment: Holy cow man, you typed all that out?

Comment: Yeah, It took quite a bit of effort to get the values just right. I used my notes as reference. (I have to do this work by hand for the quiz, so it didnt hurt to take the 30 minutes to write that)

Comment: Just for clarification, your question is "Is there a more elegant algorithm than Cramer's rule to solve systems of equations?"

Comment: No, a more elegant implementation of cramers rule in Java, basically I dont think the way I did it was the best way. There has to be a recursive way to do this smartly.

Comment: Hmmm, you mind putting that in your question? It looks to me at least that you're looking for an algorithm that's better than Cramer's Rule in general for systems of equations.

Comment: You can probably Google for a Java algorithm to compute a determinant, which looks like the biggest part of the problem.  This will involve recursion.

Comment: [Laplace expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) is probably the easiest method to implement to calculate the determinant.

Comment: @Kicsi: And the slowest. Use Leverrier-Faddeev for a faster method, or of course Gauss elimination with all bells and whistles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of, there is one way in which Cramers rule is perfect: It gives the algebraic solution of a linear system as a rational function in its coefficients.

However, practically, it has its limits. While the most perfect formula for a 2x2 system, and still good for a 3x3 system, its performance, if implemented in the straightforward way, deteriorates with each additional dimension.

An almost literal implementation of Cramers rule can be achieved with the Leverrier-Faddeev algorithm <sup>[a](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15974-faddeev-leverrier-algorithm/content/html/fadlevexample.html) [b](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmus_von_Faddejew-Leverrier)</sup>. It only requires the computation of matrix products and matrix traces, and manipulations of the matrix diagonal. Not only does it compute the determinant of the matrix A (along with the other coefficients of the characteristic polynomial), it also has the [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) or co-factor matrix A<sup>#</sup> in its iteration matrix. The interesting fact about this matrix is that it allows to write the solution of A*x=b as (A<sup>#</sup>*b)/det(A), that is, the entries of A<sup>#</sup>*b already are the other determinants required by Cramers rule.

Leverrier-Faddeev requires n<sup>4</sup>+O(n<sup>3</sup>) operations. The same results can be obtained by the more complicated Samuelson-[Berkowitz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmus_von_Samuelson-Berkowitz) algorith, which has one third of that complexity, that is n<sup>4</sup>/3+O(n<sup>3</sup>).

The computation of the determinants required in Cramers rule becomes downright trivial if the system (A|b) is first transformed into triangular form. That can be achieved by Gauß elimination, aka LU decomposition (with pivoting for numerical stability) or the QR decomposition (easiest to debug should be the variant with Givens rotations). The efficient application of Cramers rule is then backward substitution in the triangular system.

Answer (score 1):

Your method sounds good to me at least; however, I just may not be aware of any more efficient methods. The not-fun part may be figuring out how to best implement the determinant-calculating method, as apparently it's [not an inexpensive operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Calculation).

But once you know that that's working, the rest sounds pretty OK to me. Cache the determinant of the original matrix, substitute in columns, etc.

Comment: Of course, if you use, as proposed in the wiki article, a matrix decomposition (LU, QR) to compute the determinant, you can also use that same decomposition to directly solve the linear system without (explicitely) computing any other determinants.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out exactly how to do this effectively.

http://sandsduchon.org/duchon/math/determinantJava.html

Provides a method for seamless determinants, and mentions matrix decomposition. I have not learned this yet as it's not a HS level concept however I did some problems using it and it's a solid method.

Final Code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = new int[3][3];
        matrix[0] = new int[] { 3, 5, -1, -2 };
        matrix[1] = new int[] { 1, -4, 2, 13 };
        matrix[2] = new int[] { 2, 4, 3, 1 };
        int[] r = crame(matrix);
        info("x: " + r[0] + ", y: " + r[1] + ", z: " + r[2]);
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
          int[] base = matrix[i];
          if (check(base, r, base[3])) {
             info("System " + (i + 1) + " checks!");
          } else {
             info("System " + (i + 1) + " fails check!");
        }
    }
}

public static int getDet(int[][] a) {
    int n = a.length - 1;
    if (n < 0)
        return 0;
    int M[][][] = new int[n + 1][][];
    M[n] = a; // init first, largest, M to a
    // create working arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        M[i] = new int[i + 1][i + 1];
    return getDet(M, n);
} // end method getDecDet double [][] parameter

public static int getDet(int[][][] M, int m) {
    if (m == 0)
        return M[0][0][0];
    int e = 1;
    // init subarray to upper left mxm submatrix
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            M[m - 1][i][j] = M[m][i][j];
    int sum = M[m][m][m] * getDet(M, m - 1);
    // walk through rest of rows of M
    for (int i = m - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            M[m - 1][i][j] = M[m][i + 1][j];
        e = -e;
        sum += e * M[m][i][m] * getDet(M, m - 1);
    } // end for each row of matrix
    return sum;
} // end getDecDet double [][][], int

public static int[] crame(int[][] m) {
    int[] result;
    if (m.length == 2) {
        result = new int[m.length];
        int D = getDet(m);
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            result[i] = getDet(slide(m, i, m.length)) / D;
        }
    } else if (m.length == 3) {
        result = new int[m.length];
        int D = getDet(m);
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            result[i] = (getDet(slide(m, i, m.length)) / D);
        }
    } else {
        return new int[] {};
    }
    return result;
}

public static int[][] slide(int[][] base, int col, int fin) {
    int[][] copy = new int[base.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < base.length; i++) {
        int[] aMatrix = base[i];
        int aLength = aMatrix.length;
        copy[i] = new int[aLength];
        System.arraycopy(aMatrix, 0, copy[i], 0, aLength);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < base.length; i++) {
        copy[i][col] = base[i][fin];
    }
    return copy;
}

public static int product(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int p = 0;
    int[] fin = new int[(a.length - 1)];
    for (int x = 0; x < fin.length; x++) {
        fin[x] = a[x] * b[x];
    }
    for (int f : fin) {
        p += f;
    }
    return p;
}

public static boolean check(int[] a, int[] b, int z) {
    return product(a, b) == z;
}

public static void info(String log) {
    System.out.println(log);
}
```