# Cayley–Hamilton method matrix inverse

Tags: java, math, matrix, matrix-inverse

Is it possible to implement it in Java? So far I managed to implement finding the determinant of a matrix and I was thinking of doing the CayleyHamilton method but I'm stuck. I don't know how to construct the polynomial when it would come to bigger matrices. Any ideas?

Comment: Look up the LeVerrier-Faddeev algorithm, it should do more or less exactly what you want, compute the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial via traces and compute the adjugate matrix a la Horner scheme. Another (algebraic) division-free algorithm for the determinant, characteristic polynomial and adjugate is the Berkovitz algorithm which builds these from increasingly large sub-matrices. More in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23654107/3088138, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23942752/3088138

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Souriau method for Characteristic Polynomial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937481/souriau-method-for-characteristic-polynomial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep in mind that the Souriau-Leverrier-Faddeeva algorithm is numerically unstable, meaning its value is primarily theoretical.